# onLocationChanged not being called in Android Java

Tags: java, android, marker

Three months ago my code works fine, but now it didn't work. Exactly `onLocationChanged` not being called and I don't know why. I haven't changed anything for 3 months. Also, when I want to show marker on the map, it doesn't exist. I have every permission which I need. Below there is a code in Java (Android):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_demo_activity);

        new DecimalFormat("#.#", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US));

        OnClickListener();

        mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        if (mapFragment != null) {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
                    loadMap(map);
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error - Map Fragment was null!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Marker("50.06465", "19.94498", "Example");

    }


    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLAT = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
    mLON = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());

    new DoIt().execute();

}

    public void Marker(String LAT, String LON, String tit) {

    double dLAT = Double.parseDouble(LAT);
    double dLON = Double.parseDouble(LON);

    LatLng pos = new LatLng(dLAT, dLON);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        return;
    }

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    singleMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title(tit)
            .position(pos)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.icon));

}
```

Comment: Maybe the fine location is disabled in your phone

Comment: What class contains this code? Please edit your question to show this.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing several critical lines of code:

1. Your activity must implement `LocationListener`.

   ```
   class MyActivity implements LocationListener
   ```
2. You should use the `@Override` annotation on `onLocationChanged()`:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   ```
3. You need to register your listener by calling [`requestLocationUpdates()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener)):

   ```
   LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
   ```

   This step is critical in order to tell the Android system to call your `onLocationChanged()` method.

See [Location Strategies](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) in the Android Developer Guides for more details.

Comment: When I implemented third point I get an error like this "cannot resolve method requestlocationupdates" and the app went crashed.

Comment: @Zyngi Please post a new question. Be sure to include all relevant code and error messages.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice How to implement  this in a Fragment ? I asking this because requestLocationUpdates() showing error as "Cannot resolve method 'requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String, int, int, driver.arcreloaded.cogzidel.com.arcnereloaded_driver.Map_Fragment)"

Comment: @RageshDAntony You should post your own question. Read [ask] for some tips to write a good question that will attract the answers you are looking for. Be sure to include a [mcve].